# ASP.NET Core 2 .1 - How to show all data in table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.1

I don't know how to put `CustomerData` into `CustomerLists` property. I'm already using `CustomerLists = CustomerData;` but I got error:

> 'CustomerLists' is a type but is used like a variable

Can anyone explain this to me?

This is my code in Index.cshtml.cs:

```cs
namespace WebApplication1.Pages
{
    public class Pages : PageModel
    {
        public List<CustomerList> CustomerLists = new List<CustomerList>();

        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _conn;

        public Pages(ApplicationDbContext conn)
        {
            _conn = conn;
        }

        public int Message;

        public void OnGet()
        {
            var CustomerData = _conn.table_customer.ToList();
            //??
        }
    }

    public class CustomerList
    {
        public string CustomerId;
        public string Name;
        public string Address;
        public string MobileNo;
    }
}
```

Comment: `CustomerList` is a class. Probably you need `CustomerLists = CustomerData;` only when `CustomerData` is `List<CustomerList>` type, else you need cast `CustomerData` to `List<CustomerList>`. Meanwhile, in `CustomerList` class, those are fields. I doubt that you will not able to assign value to them. Change them to property by providing getter and setter. Example: `public string CustomerId { get; set; }`

Comment: Now i get where is the problem is. thanks for the explanation @YongShun

Comment: Now i get a Error ```Cannot implicitly convert type```

Comment: Hi, may I know the details for the error message?

Comment: sure. It's  Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<WebApplication1.Model.Customer>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<WebApplication1.Pages.Pages.Customer>' WebApplication1 C:\Users\Rizal\source\repos\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Pages\Index.cshtml.cs 27 Active

Comment: Look like you have two classes with same name: `Customer`. Try to specify with the namespace to avoid conflict. Example: `List<WebApplication1.Model.Customer>`.  Or create [alias for namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error mentioned, you are assigning `CustomerData` to `CustomerList` which `CustomerList` is a type. It's incorrect.

You need:

```cs
CustomerLists = CustomerData;
```

But only when `CustomerData` is a `List<CustomerList>` type.

For casting `CustomerData` to `List<CustomerList>` type, work with Linq `.Select()`.

```cs
using System.Linq;

public void OnGet()
{
    var CustomerData = _conn.tabel_customer.ToList();
    CustomerLists = CustomerData
        .Select(x => new CustomerList
        {
            // Assign property value
            CustomerId = x.CustomerId,
            ... // Remaining properties
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

Or you can straightway assign the `CustomerLists` value without the need for `CustomerData` variable.

```cs
using System.Linq;

public void OnGet()
{
    CustomerLists = _conn.tabel_customer
        .Select(x => new CustomerList
        {
            // Assign property value
            CustomerId = x.CustomerId,
            ... // Remaining properties
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

Change the fields to properties by providing getter and setter.

```cs
public class CustomerList
{
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It works ! but i don't get it about line '        .Select(x => new CustomerList
        {
            // Assign property value
            CustomerId = x.CustomerId,
            ... // Remaining properties
        })'
could you explain to me?

Comment: Hi, it is a method from System.Linq namespace to convert every item into new form in an enumerable. You may check the official document: [`IEnumerable.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0)